# Query outputs are being mixed together from Lucee (CFML) when being fetched by javascript

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, fetch-api, cfml, lucee

I have the following code..

```
async function updateItems() 
{
    await fetch('http://127.0.0.1/WebProjects/LARPLookup/Actions/Game/Items.cfm')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then((response) => {document.getElementById("nav-items").innerHTML = response;})
}

async function updateKnowledge() 
{
    await fetch('http://127.0.0.1/WebProjects/LARPLookup/Actions/Game/Knowledge.cfm')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then((response) => {document.getElementById("nav-knowledge").innerHTML = response;})
}

async function updateRelationships() 
{
    await fetch('http://127.0.0.1/WebProjects/LARPLookup/Actions/Game/Relationships.cfm')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then((response) => {document.getElementById("nav-relationships").innerHTML = response;})
}

async function updateSkills() 
{
    await fetch('http://127.0.0.1/WebProjects/LARPLookup/Actions/Game/Skills.cfm')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then((response) => {document.getElementById("nav-skills").innerHTML = response;})
}

async function updateGoals() 
{
    await fetch('http://127.0.0.1/WebProjects/LARPLookup/Actions/Game/Goals.cfm')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then((response) => {document.getElementById("nav-goals").innerHTML = response;})
}

async function updateBackground() 
{
    await fetch('http://127.0.0.1/WebProjects/LARPLookup/Actions/Game/Background.cfm')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then((response) => {document.getElementById("nav-background").innerHTML = response;})
}



async function updateCharacterPages() 
{

    updateItems();
    updateKnowledge();
    updateRelationships();
    updateSkills();
    updateGoals();
    updateBackground();

}
```

Each of those pages pulls in the full HTML of the page and puts it into a div with that ID.

```
            <cfif Relationships.recordcount GT 0>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-relationships" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-relationships-tab">
                    <cfinclude template="Relationships.cfm">
                </div>
            </cfif>

            <cfif Skills.recordcount GT 0>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-skills" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-skills-tab">
                    <cfinclude template="Skills.cfm">
                </div>
            </cfif>

            <cfif Items.recordcount GT 0>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-items" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-items-tab">
                    <cfinclude template="Items.cfm">
                </div>
            </cfif>
```

The issue is that if I run this (using a setInterval of 8 seconds), it produces things like this.

```
<tr>
<td>Player B</td>
<td>It's a good town.</td> (This is a knowledge and it should be a relationship) 
</tr>
```

or

```
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>You really like this guy</td>
</tr>
```

Sometimes, it gets it right, but others, not so much.

Where should I start to look to get this fixed?

I tried slowing down the loop, but at 8 seconds for it to process and it still messing up, when I run this for 40-60 people, it will for sure fail.

EDIT:

```
<cfset Relationships = session.relationshipsComponent.ReadRelationships(GameID = '#session.GameID#', CharacterID = '#session.CharacterID#')>

<cfoutput>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col text-center">
            <h2><u>Relationships</u></h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col text-center">
            <table class="table table-dark table-striped table-bordered border-primary">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Person</th>
                        <th scope="col">Your Thoughs about them</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody class="table-group-divider">
                    <cfloop query="Relationships">
                        <cfset NewName = session.generalComponent.ConvertText(Text = '#Relationships.ToName#', To = 'Page')>
                        <cfset NewDescription = session.generalComponent.ConvertText(Text = '#Relationships.Description#', To = 'Page')>
                        <tr>
                            <td>#NewName#</td>
                            <td>#NewDescription#</td>
                        </tr>
                    </cfloop>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</cfoutput>
```

This is an example of the table that is being created for Relationships.

EDIT 2: I have tracked down the issue to the following CFC code.

```
    <cffunction name="ConvertText" access="public" returntype="string" hint="Takes a text string and converts from and to database storage">
        <cfargument name="Text" type="string" required="Yes" hint="TextToConvert">
        <cfargument name="To" type="string" required="Yes" hint="Direction of Conversion. 'Page', 'Editor' or 'DB'">

        <cfset NewText = arguments.Text>

        <cfswitch expression="#arguments.To#">
            <cfcase value="Editor">
                <cfset NewText = replace(NewText, "<br>", CHR(13),"All")>
                <cfset NewText = replace(NewText, "[DBLQUOTE]", CHR(34),"All")> 
                <cfset NewText = replace(NewText, "[SINGLEQUOTE]", CHR(39),"All")>  
            </cfcase>
            <cfcase value="Page">
                <cfset NewText = replace(NewText, "[DBLQUOTE]", CHR(34),"All")> 
                <cfset NewText = replace(NewText, "[SINGLEQUOTE]", CHR(39),"All")>  
            </cfcase>
            <cfcase value="DB">
                <cfset NewText = replace(NewText, CHR(13), "<br>","All")>
                <cfset NewText = replace(NewText, CHR(34), "[DBLQUOTE]","All")> 
                <cfset NewText = replace(NewText, CHR(39), "[SINGLEQUOTE]","All")>
            </cfcase>
            <cfdefaultcase>
                <cfset NewText = arguments.Text>
            </cfdefaultcase>
        </cfswitch>

        <cfreturn NewText>
    </cffunction>
```

This was meant to take a piece of text and format it for an editor or the page. However, from what I am seeing, with all the updates hitting the page all at once, it is getting the wrong data halfway through. For example, I do the CFC call and put in the text "Green". It starts working on it, but then, halfway through, it changes to "Yellow" which is the proper color for one of the next sections. So I do believe that with all the imputs, it's not keeping things separated as I thought it would.

Is there a way I can be sure that if I put in Green, then no other calling of the CFC will change the Green to Yellow?

Comment: None of your code shows anything that would generate a table row. Would be easier to see the files & code that generate the content.

Comment: It's like.. As it's going through, it isn't removing the response from the first response and just using it again.. Like it comes in and sticks around for the next fetch.

Comment: The table 9 times out of 10 renders just fine. Just occasionally, it's missing a column (it's a 1 row table in the test character) or it pulls in data from the knowledges fetch.

Comment: Are there any null values or empty strings in the actual data when it renders improperly?

Comment: Yes. It sometimes returns 

```
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>You really like this guy</td>
</tr>
```
But the data is there for the first <td>. It just doesn't render said data occasionally.

Comment: Where is `updateCharacterPages` being called? I don't see that referenced. Are you server-side rendering the content of the page or server-side loading the placeholder HTML, then populating with the JavaScript functions? Also, using `async`, you're requesting data with each call, but not waiting for the data to return before moving on. So it's possible that the first data call is responding AFTER the 2nd one, so you're seeing data appear out of order. Might be better with a single call, not using `async`, that returns a complete set of data: the collection from all 5 functions.

Comment: I am server side rending the page with CFML, then using javascript to pull that page and place it within the bootstrap appropriate tab. 

As for async, doesn't await cause it to pause until the response is returned before moving on? I figured that was better than just letting them all run together.

Comment: I have figured out that it's the code above in "EDIT 2" that is causing the issue. I'm not sure how to solve it though.